# What is zero over zero?

Tags: arithmetic

I was puzzling over this question that a friend suggested to me. I have come up with no definite answer. What I thought was that:

$x/x$ is $1$ and

 $x/0$ is UNDEFINED (or some people say it's $\infty$)

To explain this you need some weird quantum mathematics. When I scoured the internet for answers, all I could find was exactly what I found myself. Does anyone have a definitive answer (even if it's just definitely impossible).

Comment: Thankyou, yes. I didn't know the right place to look

Comment: division by $0$ is undefined for real numbers

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wheel Theory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_theory), $0/0$ is designated the symbol $\bot$.

Comment: While true, I think this probably will confuse OP more than help. Wheel Theory does away with a lot of the nice properties that the reals have.